# Python: Scrabble game: scoring wildcards as 0 instead of the alphabet score

Tags: python

Problem: score the wildcards (? and *) as 0 and not the letter scores. Currently, they are being scored as the matched letter.

**To Note: what I am describing below is the exception scenario where the user enters two wildcards. In a more practical case, the user will enter a combination of alphabets and special characters (?, *) and the solution should work for such cases.**

For example, the code should work for cases like 'a?*' which is a combination of alphabets and special characters. One of the word combinations is, say 'AND' with N and D being replacement for the special characters. In such a case, the score should be A(1) + N(0) + D(0), which equates to 1 whereas the current solution would equate to A(1) + N(1) + D(2) which is 4 and is the wrong answer.

To make things simple, I am detailing the exception scenario (where user enters two special characters only).

Case in point:

Expected Output (for run_scrabble('*?')

```
(0, 'ZO')
(0, 'ZA')
(0, 'QI')
(0, 'XU')
(0, 'XI')
(0, 'OX')
(0, 'KY')
```

Actual Output:

```
(11, 'ZO')
(11, 'ZA')
(11, 'QI')
(9, 'XU')
(9, 'XI')
(9, 'OX')
(9, 'KY')
```

I believe the problematic code is at

```
else:
    valid_words.append([score_word(word_low), word_low.upper()])
```

This is the main function run_scrabble() which calls another function (score_word)

```
from wordscore import *

def run_scrabble(rack):
    
    """
    This is a modified version of the traditional scrabble game. The user plays the game
    from the command promt by running run_scrabble and provides the 'rack' as the input.
    The rack is the selection of between 2-7 words and special characters (* or ? only)
    
    The highlights of the game are
    
    1. Allow anywhere from 2-7 character tiles (letters A-Z, upper or lower case)
    2. Do not restrict the number of same tiles (e.g., a user is allowed to input ZZZZZQQ).
    3. There can be a total of only two wild cards in any user input 
       that is, one of each character: one `*` and one `?`). 
       Only use the `*` and `?` as wildcard characters. 
    4. A wildcard character can take any value A-Z. 
    5. Wildcard characters are scored as 0 points, just like in the real Scrabble game. 
       A word that just consists of two wildcards can be made, should be outputted and 
       scored as 0 points.  
    """
    
    ############### INITIALIZATION ################################
    
    # converts the input rack to lower case
    rack_low = rack.lower() 
    
    
    rack_letters = list(rack_low) 
    # converts the rack to a list of letters
    
    valid_words = [] 
    # An empty list that will eventually hold all valid words from the scrabble dictionary sowpods.txt
    
    valid_rack = True
    # A boolean condition the evaluates the contents of the rack as valid or not

    ################ VALIDATIONS ###################################    
    
    
    if (rack_low.count('?') > 1 or  rack_low.count('*')) > 1:
        return ("You have entered more than 2 special characters")
        valid_rack = False
        
        # checks the condition for only 1 of the special characters is allowed
        # ie the user cannot enter two * or two ?
        # the user can enter one * and one ?
    
    
    elif len(rack_low) > 7 or len(rack_low) < 2:
        return ("You have entered more than 7 characters or less than 2")
        valid_rack = False
        
        # checks the number of letters in the rack for a minimum of 2 and maximum of 7

    ######################################################################
    
    elif all(x.isalpha() or x in ('?', '*') for x in rack_low):
        valid_rack = True
        pass
    
         # checks if the contains only alphabets or special characters (* ?)
    
    else:
        return ('You have entered non-permitted characters. Please enter only alphabets and/or special characters * and ?')

        valid_rack = False
        
         # this condition needs rework
         # would 
    
    ######################################################################

#    Deprecated code: Replaced with condition above (would like to make this work
#    but condition is not tight enough

#     elif all(x.isalpha() == False and x not in ('?', '*') for x in rack_low):
#         valid_rack = False
#         return ('You have entered non-permitted characters. Please enter only alphabets and/or special characters * and ?')
        
    
#         # checks if the contains only alphabets or special characters (* ?)
    
#     else:
#         valid_rack = True
        
#         # this condition needs rework
        
    ######################################################################    
        
    
    if valid_rack:

        # reads the scrabble reference dictionary and creates a data list
        # after stripping the line breaks
        
        with open("sowpods.txt","r") as infile:
            raw_input = infile.readlines()#[0:1000]
            data = [datum.strip('\n') for datum in raw_input]
        
        # this is the matching algorithm that iterates through each word in the
        # scrabble dictionary (data) and checks whether the letters exists in the 
        # user input (rack). This also accounts for the two special characters (*, ?)
        # and by a process of elimination is able to implicitly substitute them for 
        # other alphabets
        
        for word in data:
            word_low = word.lower()
            temp_rack_letters = rack_letters.copy() 
            for letter in word_low:
                if letter in temp_rack_letters :
                    temp_rack_letters .remove(letter)
                elif '*' in temp_rack_letters :
                    temp_rack_letters .remove('*') 
                elif '?' in temp_rack_letters :
                    temp_rack_letters .remove('?')
                else:
                    break 
            else:
                valid_words.append([score_word(word_low), word_low.upper()])
        
        
        # Sort the valid words list in descending order of score 
        
        valid_words.sort(reverse = True)

        
        # this is the section where we print the score and word
        # note this is already in descending order in valid_words
        
        for entry in valid_words:
            score = entry[0]
            word_low = entry[1]
            print((score, word_low))

        # this is the final print of the count of all valid words
        print(len(valid_words))
    
    else:
        valid_rack = False
```

This is the second function(score_word)

```
# this is the original name of the function (had word_low)
# I know this doesn't mean much, but wanted it to be symbolic and help me understand
# the code better

#def score_word(word_low):

# renamed the function to take the parameter (rack_low
# this is symbolic as note above

def score_word(rack_low):
    
    # Deprecating the scores (from original dictionary)
    
    # scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
    #       "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
    #       "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
    #       "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
    #       "x": 8, "z": 10}
    
    # modifying scores to include the two special characters: ? and *
    
    scores = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2,
          "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3,
          "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1,
          "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4,
          "x": 8, "z": 10, "?": 0, "*": 0}    
    
    total = 0
    
#    this is the original code (with word_low)
#    for letter in word_low:
    
    # Run through all letters in the word and return the score (ie total)
    # trying to run program with letters from the rack
    
    for letter in rack_low:
        total = total + scores[letter]
    return total
```

Comment: All the words should have the same score.  You just just call score_word (once!) on the letters in the rack, not on the words that match what's in the rack, and use that as the score.

Comment: Frank, that isn't necessarily true. For example, the code should work for cases like 'a?*' which is a combination of alphabets and special characters. One of the word combinations is, say 'AND' with N and D being replacement for the special characters. In such a case, the score should be A(1) + N(0) + D(0), which equates to 1 whereas the current solution would equate to A(1) + N(1) + D(2) which is 4

Comment: Oh.  I misread your question.  Well, for each word you create, you're going to have to remember which letters are represented by blanks, and subtract their values.  You can't just call score_word() on the word you've found and get the right value.  For your "and" example, you could call `score_word("and") - score_word("n") - score_word("d"))`

Comment: Thanks Frank. I was able to solve this by creating a new rack (clean_rack) which did not have the wildcards. When passed through the scoring function, it works as planned